# Independence of random variables $A_n :=\{Y_n \le g(X_n)\},~~~n\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, independence

Let $S$ be a countable set, $g:S\to \mathbb{R}$ a function, and let $X_1, X_2,...:\Omega \to S$,
$Y_1, Y_2,...:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be independent random variables on $(\Omega,A, P)$ with the distribution
$X_n$ ~ $\mu$,   $~~~~~~~~~~$$Y_n$ ~ $Unif(0, 1)$
Now let $A_n$ be the event where $g(X_n)$ is greater or equal than $Y_n$:
$$A_n :=\{Y_n \le g(X_n)\},~~~n\in \mathbb{N}$$

By my intuition the events $A_1,A_2,..$ are also independent, but how do I proof this?
Has anyone an Idea?
Isn't the probabilty of $A_n$ equal to $\sum_{a \in \mathbb{R}} P(g(X_n) \ge a)P(Y_n \le a)$?

Comment: Why would they be indepen[den]t, by your intuition? My intuition is the opposite, which only shows that it does not mean much. And what does does the notation $X_n \sim \mu$ represent?

Comment: @TeXCub Since $Y_n$ and $g(X_n)$ are independent why would then $P(A_i | A_j)$ be not equal to $P(A_i)$? It is the notation for how the random variable is distributed. So $Y_n$ takes any numbers in the intervall $(0, 1)$ with the same probablity

Comment: $$\mathbb P(A_n)=\sum_{s\in S}\mathbb P(Y_n\leq g(s))\mathbb P(X_n=s)=\sum_{s\in S: g(s)\in[0,1]} g(s)\mathbb P(X_n=s)+\sum_{s\in S: g(s) > 1} \mathbb P(X_n=s).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say, prove pairwise independence. For $n\neq m$, 
$$\mathbb P(A_n\cap A_m) = \sum_{s_1\in S}\sum_{s_2\in S}\mathbb P(Y_n\leq g(X_n), Y_m\leq g(X_m), X_n=s_1, X_m=s_2) $$ 
$$=\sum_{s_1\in S}\sum_{s_2\in S}\mathbb P(Y_n\leq g(s_1), Y_m\leq g(s_2), X_n=s_1, X_m=s_2).$$
Since four events $\{Y_n\leq g(s_1)\}$, $\{Y_m\leq g(s_2)\}$, $\{X_n=s_1\}$, $\{X_m=s_2\}$ under the probability are independent by definition, we can rewrite the probability as
$$
\mathbb P(A_n\cap A_m) =\sum_{s_1\in S}\sum_{s_2\in S}\mathbb P(Y_n\leq g(s_1))\mathbb P(Y_m\leq g(s_2))\mathbb P(X_n=s_1)\mathbb P(X_m=s_2) $$ 
$$= 
\sum_{s_1\in S}\mathbb P(Y_n\leq g(s_1))\mathbb P(X_n=s_1)\sum_{s_2\in S}\mathbb P(Y_m\leq g(s_2))\mathbb P(X_m=s_2)=\mathbb P(A_n)\mathbb P(A_m).$$

Similar way you can prove that the probability of intersection of arbitrary events $A_{n_1},\ldots, A_{n_k}$ equals to the product of probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

The independence of $A_1,\cdots,A_n$ is obvious, because as you have said it, $\Pr[A_m|A_1,\cdots,A_{m-1}]=\Pr[A_m]$. I do not know what kind of additional rigor you're seeking in this statement.

In case you're interested in the probability of $A_n$, it's
$$
\Pr[A_n] = \int_0^1 \Pr[g(X_n)\geq t]dt,
$$
because $Y_n$ are uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
This is in the weekly exercise sheet from my class. Is there a way to prove $\Pr[A_m|A_1,\cdots,A_{m-1}]=\Pr[A_m]$.

Comment: And how to I integrate this?

Comment: From the probability expression it should be pretty obvious that $A_1,\cdots,A_n$ are independent. The way you compute that integration depends on the density of $X_n$ (i.e., $\mu$) and the functional $g$.

Comment: So there is no general solution for this.. too bad, but thank you!